# check SD 32 GB properties

Tags: sd-card

checked the capacity of the 32 GB SD card, purchased together with RaspeberryPi 3B and I saw that it gives me only 16 GB, almost totally occupied by the operating system. What should I do to use the other 16 GBs. I have to install the driver for a 5-inch Makibes Touch Screen

Comment: so, most of 16GB is used by a fresh install? sounds completely wrong to be honest. By 16GB SD card is less that 25% used by the operating system. What is the output of `sudo parted -l`

Comment: What operating system?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method is using the expand filesystem option in raspi-config but for more flexibility you can do it yourself from the command line.

Here's a previous answer I posted on how to expand the partition without losing any data [SD Card - Expanding Partition](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/78413/46241)

The example used is a partition on an external hard drive but the commands are the same other than you need to refer to the relevant SD card partition (usually /dev/mmcblk0p2) rather than  /dev/sda

Comment: note: expanding the root filesystem on the SD card, at least in raspbian, is far safer and far simpler using the expand filesystem option in  raspi-config - also, `/dev/mmcblk0p1` is NOT the partition the OP would want to expand (not that he could anyway) - it would be (more likely) `/dev/mmcblk0p2`

Comment: You're correct of course, I have amended my answer accordingly